# MS-Access: Defining Data Types while Compiling Queries

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I'm having some problems with the data types of some tables.

For example, I have:

```
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+--------------+
| Code  |  Money1  |   Money2    | Quantity |    Total     |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+--------------+
| 10001 | 100.4334 | 200.3444332 |      100 | 50,432.74642 |
+-------+----------+-------------+----------+--------------+
```

But I only want 2 digits in each column. I know how to do it from the Table (choosing `Number -> Standard -> 2 decimals`), but when I compile the query that corresponds to that Table, it breaks again.

I think I have to put `CLng()`, `CInt()` and that stuff in the query. Where? In `SELECT`, `FROM`, `TO`?. Is that OK? How `"Standard, 2 digits"` is called in that nomenclature?

Comment: What's you're query look like?

Comment: I don't have it here, but it's like:
SELECT ................. AS .............
FROM ...............
TO ...........

I mean, I select several columns from a tables and then paste them in another table

Comment: If it's just for display, you can also set the number format in query design - column properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Round([Money1], 2)` for your columns in the query or - if you are serious about rounding - the *RoundMid* function here:

[GitHub VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round.git)

Then use:

```
Select
    Code, 
    RoundMid([Money1], 2) As Money_1,
    RoundMid([Money2], 2) As Money_2,
    Quantity,
    RoundMid([Total], 2) As Total2
From
    YourTable
```

Comment: Nice! Where? In select, from, to? I think it should be in select

Comment: I'm having a problem. Access says that RoundMid doesn't exist. How can I add it?

Comment: It can be downloaded from here: [GitHub VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round.git) (link also provided above).